# Using ofstream in append mode from two different processes

Tags: c++, append, ofstream

A C++ program P1 creates ofstream on a non-existent file using ios::app. It then writes a few strings (no "\n" in them) but does not use endl (so buffer is not flushed). It then waits 2 seconds and closes the file.

Program P2 is the same as P1, except it has no wait. I was expecting P1 to overwrite whatever P2 wrote in the file because its buffer is flushed after 2 seconds, but that is not the case. Output of P2 appears properly, followed by output of P1 in the file.

After many such experiments, it appears to me that the "app" mode flushes the buffer after each write (even though endl was not used). I would like to know if others have faced similar situation, and if my conclusion is correct. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your description, the behavior is consistent with the stream buffering the data as you expect, and seeking to the end of file immediately before flushing the buffer.

Comment: This is outside the scope of the language. When we talk about flushing a file we are flushing it to the OS/FileSystem to handle. How these things handle interacting processes will depend on the OS and filesystem used.

Answer (score 0):

Your are relying on undefined behavior here - nothing guarantees that it won't flush if you don't use std::endl. Don't rely on undefined or assumed behavior - only rely on explicitly specified behavior.

To elaborate:

```
1.3.24                                                                                    [defns.undefined]
undefined behavior
behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
[ Note: Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of
behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data. Permissible undefined behavior
ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or
program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of
a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
Many erroneous program constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.
— end note ]
```

c++11 or c++03 imposes no requirements for the behavior that user2585330 is relying on.

Comment: How is he getting undefined behavior?

Comment: He is relying on it - nothing in the std guarantees that std::filebuf will be buffered - but he assumes it will be.

Comment: @IwanAucamp: "Undefined Behavior" is a term defined by the language and has a specific meaning in the context of C/C++. You are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't rely on this behaviour working.

In a similar question a while back, I wrote some code that does exactly this, and it does indeed NOT work (not necessarily that the processes overwrite each others data - I didn't see that particular behaviour, but then that's not what I was looking for - the question in that case was if the data was guaranteed to be "complete" from one process and from the other - which clearly is one of your concerns too, even if you didn't ask about that). You will get "lumps" of data from one process mixed with "lumps" of data from the other process. Exactly how they mix together depends on what platform, what the load is on the system, which day of the week it is (vague correlation, may not be true), and possibly a dozen other factors.

Technically, the C++ standard doesn't know/care about multiple processes, as far as the language is concerned, there is just one process - imagine that the language is working on an old DOS system, where there is only one process running at any given time. So the standard does not say anything about what happens if you have multiple processes using the same file.